# MS-Access chart created from a cross tab query displays a numerical ID instead of text value

Tags: ms-access, charts, lookup, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to create a chart from a cross-tab query that I have made. The row values of the chart are actually from a lookup field so instead of the actual value of the cell it shows the unique ID. I was wondering how you could make it show the actual value of the cell.

Thank you so much!

I am fairly new to using Microsoft access and haven't had any formal training except trying things here and there from an existing access database. So please excuse me if I seem clueless and need your help.

Comment: The actual value in the field is the unique ID. You will have to include the lookup table in the query by joining to the data table and use the alias value field for the CROSSTAB. First start the query as a normal SELECT that pulls in the two tables and joins them on PK/FK fields then switch to CROSSTAB.

Comment: Look at point 1 on this link:  http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm.  Not an answer, but shows the world feels your pain. :)

Comment: Yea thanks! I actually came across this link while looking for similar questions, someone had the issue with the report generation and they could fix it by having the field as a combo box? somehow I couldn't get it to work with the chart so I had to ask this question

Answer (score 0):

Make a query that is the join of your key table to the look up table.  Save that with a name.

Then recreate your cross table query and instead of using the key table as its source, use your saved query.  You will then be able to use the correct field in the rows.